# How to give color for particular field (only some column) depending on some condition in Odoo 11 in an one2many tree?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I would like give color for particular field value in one2many form view. This is my sample code.

```
 <field name="custom_order_line" mode="tree,kanban" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'validate')]}">
    <tree colors="red:customs_sale_price &lt; price_unit;green:customs_sale_price &gt; price_unit;" string="Customs Order Lines" editable="bottom">
        <field name="customs_sale_price" colors="green:state == 'draft' "/>
        <field name="customs_cost_price" colors="red:customs_cost_price &lt; customs_sale_price"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: I think  they have used button. I could not understand kindly explain.

Comment: I have removed the "possible duplicated" because you say that you want to use a condition. There should be a module that allows to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a module ([**`web_tree_dynamic_colored_field`**](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/11.0/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field)) that does what you need. Check the link

Example changing the `bg_color` color:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="View name">
        ...
        <field name="name" options='{"bg_color": "red: customer == True"}'/>
        ...
    </tree>
</field>
```

Example changing the `fg_color` color:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="View name">
        ...
        <field name="name" options='{"fg_color": "white:customer == True"}'/>
        ...
    </tree>
</field>
```

**Note:** that you should always use single quotes for fields `options` and wrap nested values in double quotes since `options` is a JSON object.

## [Decorators](https://www.iwesabe.com/blog/how-to-add-colors-to-tree-view-in-odoo)

If you just want to color rows you can use decorators (only for the 11 version)

```
decoration-bf - shows the line in BOLD 
decoration-it - shows the line in ITALICS 
decoration-danger - shows the line in LIGHT RED 
decoration-info - shows the line in LIGHT BLUE 
decoration-muted - shows the line in LIGHT GRAY 
decoration-primary - shows the line in LIGHT PURPLE 
decoration-success - shows the line in LIGHT GREEN 
decoration-warning - shows the line in LIGHT BROWN
```

Syntax

```
<tree decoration-type="field=='value'">
```

Example

```
<tree decoration-success="state=='done'">
```

Comment: Check if this works @anand because it may only works within the tree view

Comment: Thanks for your answer ChesuCR. But it's not working for form field values.